# Как реализовать на VUE переход из меню навигации. На другую страницу, на конкретный TAB?

Tags: vue.js, router, tabs

```
Вот меню навигации, должен осуществляется переход на другую страницу, но на разные табы.
 
 <p class="info-block">
    <span @click="$router.push('/About')" class="title">About</span>
        <ul>
           <li @click="$router.push('/About')" class="list">Organisation</li>
           <li @click="$router.push('/About')" class="list">Mission</li>
           <li @click="$router.push('/About')" class="list">Scams</li>
        </ul>
   </p>

сами табы 

    <el-tabs v-model="activeName" @tab-click="handleClick">
      <el-tab-pane label="Scams" name="first">
         страница 1
      </el-tab-pane>
      <el-tab-pane label="Organisation" name="second" id="Organisation" >
         страница 2
      </el-tab-pane>
      <el-tab-pane label="Mission" name="third">
       страница 3
      </el-tab-pane>
    </el-tabs>

    export default {
      components: { },
      data() {
        return {
          activeName: "first",
        };
      },
      methods: {
        handleClick(tab, event) {
          console.log(tab, event);
        },
      },
    };
```

Comment: вставить id таба в hash ссылки и потом установить как значение activeName

Comment: <li @click="$router.push('/About#Organisation')" class="list">Organisation</li>

<el-tab-pane label="Organisation" name="second" id="Organisation" >
              text2
          </el-tab-pane>
export default {
  components: { },
  data() {
    return {
      activeName: "Organisation",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick(tab, event) {
      console.log(tab, event);
    },
  },
};

Не работает, activeName работает не по ID, а по "name" таба